# Output of a bunch of zeros after code is finished

Tags: java, arrays

I am having issues with the code printing the Matched numbers. The result of my terminal looks like:

```
Choose Five Numbers: 5 6 7 8 99
Choose Mega Ball: 56
You Chose Following:
5 6 7 8 99 Mega Ball - 56.
DRAW RESULT: 
15 14 5 11 19 Mega Ball - 14.
Matched Numbers are: 
You are a Winner!!
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I am not sure what I am missing or if my code isn't all in the correct order or if I'm misplacing brackets and it's not reading something. Thanks

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1KRP   {

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {

        int[] randomNumbers = new int[6]; // Stores 6 random numbers
        int[] inputNumbers = new int[6]; // Stores 6 numbers given by user
        ArrayList<Integer> equalNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Stores matched numbers
        Random rand = new Random();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.print("Choose Five Numbers: ");
        int[] numbers = new int[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Choose Mega Ball: ");
        numbers[5] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You Chose Following:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Mega Ball - " + numbers[5] + ".");


        //Generates 6 Random Numbers in the range 1 -20
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*20 + 1);
        }
        System.out.println("DRAW RESULT: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Mega Ball - " + numbers[5] + ".");

        //Comparing random numbers array and user input numbers array
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                if (randomNumbers[i] == inputNumbers[j]) { // Comparing matched numbers
                    equalNumbers.add(randomNumbers[i]); // Adding matched number to Array list
                }
            }
        }
        // Printing final output
        if (equalNumbers.size() != 0) { // At least one matched number is there

            System.out.println("Matched Numbers are: ");
            System.out.println("You are a Winner!!");
            for(int i:equalNumbers)
            {
                System.out.println(i); // Printing list of matched numbers
            }
        }
        else { // If no matched numbers
            System.out.println("You are a Loser.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never put anything in `randomNumbers` and `inputNumbers` so `if (randomNumbers[i] == inputNumbers[j]) ` is always true, because they both contain only zeroes, you add those zeroes to `equalNumbers` and then print it.

Comment: Typo: `numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*20 + 1);` Should be `randomNumbers`.

Comment: Unless your assignment requires you to use arrays for this, consider using a `Set<Integer>` for both sets of numbers. Then `retainAll()` will give you the matched numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You never use your two arrays `randomNumbers` and `inputNumbers`. Instead, you always use `numbers`. So, when comparing your first two arrays, they contain only zeros, and hence are always equal.

Also, when checking for equality, you generate all permutations of the indices `i` and `j`. But you are only really interested in the cases where `i == j`, the second, nested loop is redundant. This is why instead of only printing five zeros, it prints 25 zeros. Change it two the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (randomNumbers[i] == inputNumbers[i]) { 
        equalNumbers.add(randomNumbers[i]); 
    }
}
```

Finally, notice how the loop only has five iterations. Not sure if that is intended, but this way you do not compare the "Megaball".